# Why was the alien released on board the Covenant?

Tags: alien-franchise, character-motivation, alien-covenant

Why did

> David, pretending to be Walter

let the Alien out on board the ship?

He already had the crew fooled, so all he had to do was to wait for them to go into hypersleep and then he could conduct as many experiments as he wanted.

Letting the Alien out was very risky: he lost three perfectly good bodies (the one with his cheek burned-out with acid and the couple in the shower) and the alien could also possibly kill all the colonists or even destroy the whole space ship.

Comment: The [edits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/159457/revisions) hid a minor point behind spoiler markup while exposing one of the biggest reveals in the movie directly in the title and first sentence? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I saw the scene, he didn't know Lope had been impregnated. I'm guessing he assumed the acid burns meant the facehugger had been removed in time.

His plan was that no-one recognise him as an imposter. Daniels only realised his identity when David didn't understand her cabin reference.